# How can I get JQueryUI sortable to 'revert' faster?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

JQuery's `sortable` has an option to `revert` the item that the user drags back in line with the rest, but the animation is a little slow.

Is there a simple way to specify `'fast'` like some of the other methods?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

<del>It appears to be undocumented</del>*, but setting the `revert` property to a number will treat that as the speed (or more specifically the duration in ms). So something like this gives a pretty quick revert animation:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({revert: 100});
```

(Aside: It's a pity they haven't kept it consistent with draggables, which use [`revertDuration`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7.2/Draggable#option-revertDuration) to specify the speed of the revert.)

***Edit**: It looks like in the latest version [it is now an officially documented feature](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7.2/Sortable#option-revert).